# What is the internal kotlin modifier in byte code?

Tags: java, kotlin

1. If I create library with kotlin and mark some class with internal, how does it look from java with no Kotlin plugin in maven and in IDE, it will be just public or package or JVM has other modifiers that java has not?
2. if I use in a module one class with @service annotation and mark it internal, and use this module in other module, Does it work?
3. How does  it look in byte code?

Comment: These declarations are public by the time they get to the bytecode, but their names are mangled so that Java clients won't accidentally call them. So... It's not perfectly safe, but it's indicated that they aren't supposed to be called. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#visibility

Comment: @zsmb13 Why isn't this an answer?

Comment: @zsmb13 what do you mean mangled, for example I have class with "CalculateRepository" with "calculate" function, how these name will be mangled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These declarations are public by the time they get to the bytecode, but their names are mangled so that Java clients won't accidentally call them. So... It's not perfectly safe, but it's indicated that they aren't supposed to be called. (This is in the documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#visibility)).

For example, if you mark a function called `calculate` internal, it might end up with the name `calculate$modulename` in the bytecode. (There do seem to be some cases where names aren't mangled, at least based on my testing of this.)

Additionally, IntelliJ will also detect if a declaration was compiled with `internal` visibility (since there's metadata indicating this), and show you an error when you attempt to use it.

Comment: Does it mean that if I don't use Kotlin plugins in ide and use such class from library, it will not compile?

Comment: I believe it will compile, and it might do so without warning. Really, you should create a project with two modules and try these edge cases. The general takeaway is that internal things will always be callable from Java code if someone wants to do so.

Comment: I mean about library, not module.

Comment: Accessing a library will work the same way as another module in terms of the `internal` modifier.

Comment: sorry, I mean accessing to such the class(internal class CalculateRepository") of a library, when I don't use any kotlin plugin. I don't get any highlights, ok, it's good. but what about compile, will it compile if not what error I will get?

Comment: Oh, yes, since these are actually public any code that calls into them (given that they're using the right identifiers, should they be mangled) will compile and run fine!

Comment: It's very strange, it works only with plugin and  without any plugin it doesn't work? why he entered this modifier and it's mangled?

Comment: It's to indicate to Java users that they shouldn't use them, even though they're accessible.

Comment: If it will be compiled and how users will indicate it?

Comment: Java users are meant to recognize that the `$` and other unusual symbols in the mangled name are not for normal consumption, and that therefore they shouldn't be using those in their own code.